# Xamarin.Forms NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a NavigationPage but I'm doing something wrong. Here's my stacktrace message: "Sequence contains no elements." Can someone help me pinpoint what's wrong with my code? [I uploaded an image of an error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQDaw.png)

This is the code-behind for the xaml page:

```
namespace Quickies
{
public partial class QuickiesPage : NavigationPage
  {
    public QuickiesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my "App" class

```
namespace Quickies
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage (new QuickiesPage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation page constructor accepts Xamarin.Forms.Page object. You are trying to send a Navigation Page object.
You can either do :

```
public partial class QuickiesPage : ContentPage
```

or (since I am not sure what you are trying to do)

```
MainPage = new QuickiesPage ();
```